# UIPickerView not selected rows

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am working on UIPickerView for selection of time. So far I managed to get it to have custom font and to teoreticly spin endless. But now I am trying to get it to have only one row on screen. I understand it is not possible to have only one row, so I was thinking if it is possible to make the fontcolor in the rows that are not selected (in center) different color (clearcolor). That would make an effect that there is only one row.

Or if that is not possible if at least there is a way how to remove selected row top and bottom border.

EDIT1: Or if anyone knows any good tutorial/example on how to make your own picker. Something like having a label showing a number and you can swipe ower it to scroll these numbers.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make a `UIScrollView`. Embed a single date label in it. And then in an appropriate delegate method, animate the initial label out, and a second label back to the initial label's position.